# how can i use this code only for one button?

Tags: android, sample

how can i use this code only for one button?
i cant change this !

```
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        boolean[] newButtonStates = new boolean[24];
```

`int action = event.getAction();
    boolean isDownAction = (action & 0x36) == 0x36 || action ==   MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;

    for (int touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < event.getPointerCount(); touchIndex++)
    {
        // find button for location
        int x = (int) event.getX(touchIndex);
        int y = (int) event.getY(touchIndex);

        for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < buttons.size(); buttonIndex++)
        {
            View button = buttons.get(buttonIndex);
            int[] location = new int[2];
            button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            int buttonX = location[0];
            int buttonY = location[1];

            Rect rect = new Rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonX + button.getWidth(), buttonY + button.getHeight());
            if (rect.contains(x, y))
            {
                newButtonStates[buttonIndex] = isDownAction;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < newButtonStates.length; index++)
    {
        if (buttonStates[index] != newButtonStates[index])
        {
            buttonStates[index] = newButtonStates[index];
            View button = buttons.get(index);
            toggleButtonSound(button, newButtonStates[index]);
        }
    }

    return true;`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this code? A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Implement onTouchListener for button.

Comment: if i touch the button with drag finger on button from other location of screen what this event? please give me a sample

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do is this:

```
Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);    
myBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                        // Do what you want
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: no i dont want this. when drag finger from another state of screen on button this code not work.